# Clear checkbox and textarea onload javacript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a javascript code to clear checkbox and textarea when the page loads. The code works on Firefox but it does not on google chrome. Do have any idea how to change my code to be fonctional on both browsers ?

Call the the javascript function onload:

```
<body onload="eraseTest()">
```

in the page the javascript code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ampli" id="ampli" value="ampli" onchange="valueChanged()">Ampli?


<script type="text/javascript">

    function valueChanged(){
    if (document.getElementById('ampli').checked) 
        {document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'block';
            
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv2").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

<script>
//Function to reset onload comment textarea and checkbox ampli+input fields of ampli
function eraseTest(){
document.getElementById("comment").value="";
document.getElementById("ampli").checked=false;
document.getElementById("geneName").value="";
document.getElementById("AmpliGene").value="";
}
</script>

<div id="subnetmaskdiv" style="display:none;">Gene:<input type="text" name="geneName" id="geneName"/>
<br/>Valeur Ampli:<input type="text" size="3" name="AmpliGene" id="AmpliGene"/></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not really descriptive. Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: On Firefox, when I go back on page, the script uncheck the checkbox and clear the textarea, on google chrome it does not perform the action. In the console of google chrome, i have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at valueChanged (RapportForm.html:113)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange`

Comment: Can you try add `onload="eraseTest()"` on `subnetmaskdiv2` ?